# Webmatrix image upload and ImageMagick

Tags: image, image-processing, razor, webmatrix

I have a simple image upload page which works really well:

```
WebImage photo = null;
var newFileName = "";
var imagePath = "";

if(IsPost){
    using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/" + imagePath))){
        using (var newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap)){
            newBitmap.SetResolution(72f, 72f);
            newBitmap.Save("file300.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

    }
    var image = "UPDATE PropertyInfo SET PrimaryImage = @0 WHERE PropertyID = @1";
    db.Execute(image, newFileName, rPropertyId);
}
```

Now i also want to use ImageMagick to convert any images uploaded using this form to 72dpi. I have the command line i need to do this, but i don't now how to apply it to the upload process?

convert c:\image.jpg -density 72 c:\image.jpg

Should i do this during the upload process, or once the file has already been uploaded to a server. Is there any way of initiating a command prompt from within WebMatrix?

Answer (score 0):

It seems easier to use existing .NET features to manage the DPI, namely with the [System.Drawing.Bitmap.SetResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setresolution.aspx) method

```
using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/" + imagePath))){
   using (var newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap)){
       newBitmap.SetResolution(72f, 72f);
       newBitmap.Save("file300.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   }
}
```

However, you can also use the [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) method to run .exes via C# code.

Comment: I've updated my code (shown above) and getting the following error: " The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Add `@using System.Drawing;` to the top of your file.

Comment: that removed the original error, now getting this one "The name 'ImageFormat' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Add `@using System.Drawing.Imaging;` to the top of your file as well.